# How to close a dropdown menu on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

If you go to this [dev site](http://workwave.joomlatest01.mms-dev.com/) (it's a Joomla site using bootstrap) and view on 1023px wide screen or smaller (or any smartphone), there is a hamburger menu. If you click it, it drops down a menu and if you click "Learn More", it jumps to a form (because it's really just an anchor). However, the dropdown menu stays open (because it's not going to a new page I guess).

Is there an easy way to add some code that basically says "any dropdown menu click should CLOSE the dropdown menu"?

Here is the code for the menu when it's expanded (first nav tag is probably all that's important)...

```
<nav class="t3-navbar-collapse navbar-collapse collapse in"><ul class="nav navbar-nav level0">
<li>
<a href="/index.php">Home </a>

</li>
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="/index.php/features" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#">Features <b class="caret"></b></a>


<ul class="level1 dropdown-menu"><li>
<a href="/index.php/features/scheduling-routing">Scheduling &amp; Routing </a>

</li><li>
<a href="/index.php/features/billing-invoicing">Billing &amp; Invoicing </a>

</li><li>
<a href="/index.php/features/mobile-workforce">Mobile Workforce </a>

</li><li>
<a href="/index.php/features/office-staff-persona">Office Staff Persona </a>

</li><li>
<a href="/index.php/features/owner-persona">Owner Persona </a>

</li><li>
<a href="/index.php/features/field-worker-persona">Field Worker Persona </a>

</li></ul></li>
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="/index.php/industries" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#">Industries <b class="caret"></b></a>


<ul class="level1 dropdown-menu"><li>
<a href="/index.php/industries/cleaning">Cleaning </a>

</li><li>
<a href="/index.php/industries/lawn">Lawn </a>

</li><li>
<a href="/index.php/industries/pest">Pest </a>

</li><li>
<a href="/index.php/industries/hvac">HVAC </a>

</li></ul></li>
<li>
<a href="/index.php/pricing">Pricing </a>

</li>
<li class="active dropdown">
<a href="/index.php/about" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#">About <b class="caret"></b></a>


<ul class="level1 dropdown-menu"><li class="current active">
<a href="/index.php/about/resources">Resources </a>

</li><li>
<a href="/index.php/about/support">Support </a>

</li><li>
<a href="/index.php/about/security">Security </a>

</li></ul></li>
<li class="">
<a href="#leadform">Learn More</a>

</li>
<li>
<a href="#leadform">Contact</a>

</li>
<li>
<a href="/index.php/log-in">Log In </a>

</li>
</ul></nav>
```

And then when it collapses again, the classes in the nav tag look like this...

```
<nav class="t3-navbar-collapse navbar-collapse collapse" style="height: 1px;">
```

So it looks like that class of "in" needs to go away. Therefore, I am trying this jquery, but it isn't working.  Shouldn't this work?

```
jQuery(function($) {
$("li a").click(function() {
   $("nav.t3-navbar-collapse").removeClass( "in" );
});
});
```

Comment: yikes, sorry, clearly nobody is happy with what I asked. What did I do wrong?  I'm new so I'd like to learn what I did wrong and correct my mistake.  I didn't include any code because I don't know what code is controlling the menu currently.

Comment: People normally like actual code and a description of the problem, not just a description of the problem. If you isolate your problem and put it in a fiddle people are more likely to respond

Comment: Thank you zgood, I will try to do that and update the question once I do.  I appreciate it...

Comment: Please see [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for info on improving your question. Right now, your question has no code and only exists as a reference to an off-site resource. If that site goes down, this question becomes useless to others and completely unanswerable.

Comment: Hopefully what I added is more in line with good questions :)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the bad luck on the first question, I actually just did this recently so I have a snippet on hand for you.

Basically what you want to tell the code to do is close the nav when you click an anchor, so you target the `a` and use a `slideUp` property.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
        $("Your_Nav_ID").slideUp('slow');
    });
});
```